# Customize PHP SOAP Body Parameters according to WSDL File format

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am trying to send SOAP request to remote Server and following request message is required to send.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:F1>
<id>2323</id>
</ns1:F1>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But My Request is like this

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:F1/>
<param1>2323</param1>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I used general php soap_client function from WAMP server like this.

```
 $client = new SoapClient("name.wsdl",array(
    "trace"      => 1,
    "exceptions" => 0 );

  $result = $client->F1($value);
```

How can I convert 2nd out put into first one. I need to change parameter name is change to F1 from param1 and correctly closed Body tag.

Answer (score 3):

How are you constructing value? You may need to create this variable as a multidimensional array if the web service is looking for a complex type. You can look for clues in the WSDL file if there is one.

```
$value = array(
           'F1' = array(
                    'id' => 2323
                       )
               );
```

Answer (score 2):

First, check that your WSDL URL is correct, as SoapClient uses the WSDL from the service to know what to name your parameters.

You can also specify your parameter name literally:

```
$response = $client->__soapCall('ns1:F1', array(new SoapParam('2323','id')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Parameters inside __soapCall function,

```
$client = new SoapClient("name.wsdl");

$arrayname = array(
  XXXXXXXXX
);

$response = $client->__soapCall("F1", array($arrayname ));
```